# Register 2D image - 3D model

Tags: python, reference-implementation, projection

I have 2D pictures of an airplane of a specific model, taken with a simple camera, and a 3D point cloud model of this airplane.
I would like to project the pictures onto the 3D model (cloud of points) based on control points that I manually locate on both ends. This should allow me to calculate distances on the 2D pictures.
Is there a programming library that does this? I program in Python mostly.

Answer (score -1):

You could easily use OpenCV (https://opencv.org/) to do that. Check out the [solvePnP](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d53/tutorial_py_pose.html) functionality. Here is a [demo on head pose estimation](https://learnopencv.com/head-pose-estimation-using-opencv-and-dlib/).